# Wordpress PHP shortcode, get_the_content by id won't display custom post type content

Tags: php, wordpress, function, custom-post-type, shortcode

Currently working on a project where I want to display employees' business cards by a shortcode, for instance `[person id="1"]` or [`person name="bob"]`.

I've created a seperate post type for employees, where title=name, content=contact info and thumbnail=image.

The problem is that title and thumbnail shows the right employee data, but `get_the_content($post_id)` displays the content of my first post "Welcome to ...! This is your first post...".

```
function display_person($atts, $content){

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'posts_per_page' => '1',
        'post_type' => 'person',
        'post_id' => null,
        'caller_get_posts' => 1)
   , $atts));

  global $post;

  $posts = new WP_Query($atts);
  $output = '';
    if ($posts->have_posts())
        while ($posts->have_posts()):
            $posts->the_post();
            $out = '<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 person-container margin-top">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 hidden-xs person-thumbnail no-padding">
            '.get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'thumbnail-person').'
        </div>
        <div class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm col-xs-4 person-thumbnail no-padding">
            '.get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'thumbnail-person-small').'
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-8 person no-padding">
            <h3>'.get_the_title($post_id).'</h3>
            '.get_the_content($post_id).'
        </div>
    </div>
</div>';
            $out .='</div>';
    endwhile;
  else
    return;

  wp_reset_query();
  return html_entity_decode($out);
}
add_shortcode('person', 'display_person');
```

How do I get `get_the_content($post_id)` to display the custom post content?

Comment: [`get_the_content()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content) do not accept a Post-ID as argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems a bit faulty.

```
// this is your shortcode
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
    'post_type' => 'person',
    'post_id' => null,
    'caller_get_posts' => 1)
, $atts));
```

It should look like this (based on the assumption, that $atts' elements are taken from the shortcode parameters):

```
// you extract the parameters into variable names
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 'posts_per_page_var',
    'post_type'        => 'post_type_var',
    'post_id'          => 'post_id_var',
    'caller_get_posts' => 'caller_get_posts_var')
, $atts));

// creating the array of arguments for the query
$new_atts = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => $posts_per_page_var,
    'post_type'        => $post_type_var,
    'post_id'          => $post_id_var,
    'caller_get_posts' => $caller_get_posts_var
);
$posts = new WP_Query($new_atts);
// and go on with your code...
```

It think this should solve your problem.

Longer tutorial:

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/06/how-to-create-your-own-wordpress-shortcodes/

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly!

Comment: Also added$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);

Comment: I'm happy that I could help! :) Thank you for voting!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: [`get_the_content()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content) do not accept a Post-ID as argument.

If your shortcode is just for **one person**, you can do it like this:

```
function display_person( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => false,
        'name' => false
    ), $atts, 'person' );


    if ( $atts['id'] ) {
        $person = get_post( $atts['id'] );
    } else if ( $atts['name'] ) {
        // todo
    }

    $image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $person->ID, 'medium' );
    $name = $person->post_title;
    $content = wpautop( $person->post_content );

    $output = ""; // todo


    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'person', 'display_person' );
```

This code example is not ready to use.